# How to write a shell script to restart jupyter server before i start working on ipynb

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter-lab

How to kill the server and restart using shell script while multiple jupyter notebook's are running on the server.

Answer (score 1):

As I've understood you want to create a script that'll restart jupyter-notebook server.

I'd recommend this approach:

Open .sh file

```
emacs some_name.sh
```

Write this to the file and save

```
ps
echo 'Print PID of process you want to kill:'
read PID
while kill $PID; do 
    sleep 1
done
echo 'Process killed'
jupyter-notebook
```

Don't forget to make the file executable

```
chmod +x some_name.sh
```

After that you can add this file to your /usr/local/bin folder so you could use it as a command.

Example:

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Yup. Thank you buddy.!!